# Syntax to check if NSInteger is nil or not?

Tags: objective-c

The following is returning an error because evidently I cannot compare an NSInteger or int to nil.  Can anyone suggest syntax to do this

```
NSInteger *lastID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"lastID"]==nil ? @1 : [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"lastID"];
```

Comment: `integerForKey:@"lastID"]==''` no?

Comment: A tip on tags: This is a Objective-C / Cocoa question. It's unrelated to Xcode or iOS.

Comment: =='' returned expected expression (red) and empty character count (yellow) errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSInteger lastID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"lastID"] == 0 ? 1 : [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"lastID"];
```

NSInteger is a primitive type. nil is for objects. `0` check, checks is your userDefaults' integer value assigned a value. If it didn't assigned, it returns 0.

Comment: This is much simpler than going back and forth between primitives and objects.  Hopefully, there is nothing wrong with storing the info as a primitive.

Comment: This answer is simply not correct. `NSNotFound` does NOT equal `0`. The comparison in the ternary operator will only be true when a *stored* value (not unfound) is equal to `NSNotFound` (i.e. `LONG_MAX`). Furthermore, you still define `lastID` as a pointer type, which is wrong in this context, as it's a primitive, and you aren't doing pointer logic.

Comment: I ran the code and @greymouser 's comment is actually true. I'm confused now because before this time in my situations this code was working for me. If there is no value in userDefaults as an integer it comes '0'. So I edited my answer.

Comment: @user1904273 Please review my answer

Comment: @CandostDagdeviren If you remove the `*` from `NSInteger *lastID = ...`, then the answer will be technically correct. As written, it is still very misleading -- as the NSInteger is not useful as a pointer in this context -- that it's incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

NSInteger is a primitive type, not an object. I'm quite sure that an NSInteger* is *not* what you want, but an NSInteger. integerForKey returns an NSInteger, not an NSInteger*.

Comment: If I remove the star, I get Incompatible operand types aka NSNumber * and NSinteger aka int  error  and comparison between pointer and incompatible pointer and Integer NSInteger aka int and void error

Answer (score 3):

NSInteger is a primitive, not an NSObject, so any hypothetical comparison to `nil` would effectively be comparing to numeric zero.

Since you are using the ternary operator to assign lastID to the boxed NSNumber `@1` if the result would be `nil`, then it seems what you want to do is store an `NSNumber` in the defaults, use `objectForKey:` to retrieve it, and use `integerValue` on the retrieved NSNumber to get the primitive value.

If you do indeed want to store primitives, that's fine, but you'll need to change your logic to not expect `nil`, which is only pertinent to sublcasses of NSObject, basically.

UPDATE: an example app.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

enum {
    MyIdTypeUnrecognized = 0,
    MyIdTypeInvalid      = 1
} myIdType;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *key = @"lastID";
        NSInteger lastID = -100;

        [defaults removeObjectForKey:key];

        NSLog(@"Case 1: should find 0, and set lastID to 1.");
        lastID = [defaults integerForKey:key];
        lastID = (lastID == MyIdTypeUnrecognized) ? MyIdTypeInvalid : lastID;
        NSLog(@"--- lastID:%ld", lastID);

        NSLog(@"Case 2: Set lastID to 2, then try to fetch.");
        lastID = -100;
        [defaults setInteger:2 forKey:key];
        [defaults synchronize];
        lastID = [defaults integerForKey:key];
        lastID = (lastID == MyIdTypeUnrecognized) ? MyIdTypeInvalid : lastID;
        NSLog(@"--- lastID:%ld", lastID);
    }
}
//2015-09-04 10:04:38.075 nsnotfound[66983:5231434] Case 1: should find 0, and set lastID to 1.
//2015-09-04 10:04:38.076 nsnotfound[66983:5231434] --- lastID:1
//2015-09-04 10:04:38.076 nsnotfound[66983:5231434] Case 2: Set lastID to 2, then try to fetch.
//2015-09-04 10:04:38.076 nsnotfound[66983:5231434] --- lastID:2
```

I suggested using `NSNumber` earlier, as your question used a boxed `NSNumber` -- `@1`. `@1` is simply shorthand for `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]`. If you don't want to use objects, you can definitely use primitives.

The example above uses both zero and one as sentinel values for your "unfound" and "invalid" IDs. All other IDs should be usable by your app logic. I hope this helps.

Comment: the reason I tried NSInteger is that syntax uses the word integerForKey.  Also I next want to increment the number by 1 and resave it.  What I want to do is find out if it has ever ben saved before, if not make it 1 and if so get saved value that I will then increment.

Comment: If I do store primitives, what would I compare to it not nil?  If not, it sounds like I have to go through step of recasting as a primitive to iterate it, going back to NSNumber object and finally saving object again which sounds more cumbersome.

Comment: I got it to work going back and forth between the types but it took quite a bit of code.

Comment: @user1904273 If you store positive integers you can use NSUInteger (unsigned) and any negative number as a sentinel value to represent "invalid id". For example, `#define INVALID_ID -1`. If `0` is also an invalid id value, you can continue to use NSInteger, and instead of `-1` for your sentinel value, just use 0.

Comment: @user1904273 Since NSUserDefaults `-integerForKey:` method specifically returns `0` if the key is not found, as documented, then your best bet is to consider `0` the invalid id value, so that it doesn't matter if `0` was stored or if the key wasn't found, and returned `0`.

Comment: @user1904273 updated my answer with an example -- the current accepted answer is 100% incorrect as written currently.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve this number to `NSNumber` which is an object and that way you can check if it is nil or not.

Answer (score 0):

NSInteger is basically a typecast of Int in 32 bit or long in 64 bit, as you compare int in similar way you can compare NSInteger.It will never be nil.

Answer (score 0):

`NSInteger` isn't an object, its a primitive type stored as a `NSNumber` inside `NSUserDefaults`. Checking for existence of primitive types is a bit tricky, as its non-existence is equivalent to nil or 0. The cleanest way to get its value and get a default value if it doesn't exist is probably this way:

`NSNumber *lastID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastID"] ?: @1;`

This would return you lastID if it exists, otherwise you get a `NSNumber` with a value of 1.